# Filtering related entities in entity framework 6

Tags: entity-framework, repository-pattern, dbcontext

I want to fetch the candidate and the work exp where it is not deleted. I am using repository pattern in my c# app mvc.

Kind of having trouble filtering the record and its related child entities

I have list of candidates which have collection of workexp kind of throws error saying cannot build expression from the body.

I tried putting out anonymous object but error still persist, but if I use a VM or DTO for returning the data the query works.

It's like EF doesn't like newing up of the existing entity within its current context.

```
var candidate = dbcontext.candidate
    .where(c=>c.candiate.ID == id).include(c=>c.WorkExperience)
    .select(e=>new candidate
    {
        WorkExperience = e.WorkExperience.where(k=>k.isdeleted==false).tolist() 
    });
```

Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call `ToList` in the expression that is traslated to SQL. Alternatively, you can start you query from selecting from `WorkExperience` table. I'm not aware of the structure of your database, but something like this might work:

```
var candidate = dbcontext.WorkExperience
    .Include(exp => exp.Candidate)
    .Where(exp => exp.isdeleted == false && exp.Candidate.ID == id)
    .GroupBy(exp => exp.Candidate)
    .ToArray() //query actually gets executed and return grouped data from the DB
    .Select(groped => new {
        Candidate = grouped.Key,
        Experience = grouped.ToArray()
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var candidate = 
    from(dbcontext.candidate.Include(c=>c.WorkExperience)
         where(c=>c.candiate.ID == id)
         select c).ToList().Select(cand => new candidate{WorkExperience = cand.WorkExperience.where(k=>k.isdeleted==false).tolist()});
```

Comment: @user1516947 This is more like your first approach but you have to use the constructor outside the sql environment, that's the error you were getting. The first ToList() executes the sql statement generated by EF, so will bring a list of 1 object (if found) and pass the list to the select. The second ToList() was just copy and paste of your code, I don't know if it is required.
I prefer this approach because is simpler than the grouping, and explicit what you are doing.